# How do I convert the nodes returned when doing a path search in Neo4j?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

I have [an app](https://github.com/dhappy/argus) where I'm loading a bunch of ebooks along with metadata into Neo4j with the goal of producing an IPFS directory tree to input into [another app](https://github.com/dhappy/mimis).

It is a rails application, so I have a `Book` class as such:

```
class Book 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :title, type: String
  property :author, type: String
  property :created_at, type: DateTime
  property :updated_at, type: DateTime

  has_many :in, :contexts, type: :FOR
  has_one :out, :cover, type: :CVR, model_class: :Content
  has_one :out, :content, type: :DAT
end
```

In the [rake task to export to IPFS](https://github.com/dhappy/argus/blob/neo4j-trial/lib/tasks/export.rake#L4), I am using the following to perform the query:

```
q = Neo4j::ActiveBase.current_session.query(
  "MATCH path = (n:Context)-[s:SUB*]->(m:Context)-[f:FOR]->(o:Book) WHERE n.name = '∅' RETURN DISTINCT path LIMIT 500"
)
```

This is returning the paths that I want, but `q.first.path.nodes.first` (and all the other nodes) are `Neo4j::Core::Node`s. I want to access the `cover` and `content` relationships of my `Book` class, but can't. For example:

```
q.each do |ret|
  nodes = ret.path.nodes
  nodes.shift # remove ∅
  book = nodes.pop
  path = nodes.map(&:name)
  if book.content
    system('ipfs', 'files', 'cp', "/ipfs/#{book.content.ipfs_id}", "/#{path.join('/')}/index.epub")
  end
  ⋮
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the uuid to look up the book:

```
book = Book.find(nodes.pop.properties[:uuid])
```